Carbon frame impact, what should I do?
I have a Yeti SB-5c(carbon) full suspension, rides great.  Today I was riding, and the downtube hit a root covered in leaves(around 15-20mph). I was at the start of my ride at that point, and kept riding it for around 1hr 30min.
So my question to everyone is, what should I do now? does it look bad enough to total the frame, to fix, or should I just get it checked out?
It passed the coin-tap test, doesn't flex, no signs of large structural damage, and seems too be mostly powder coat damage.
Here's some pictures or what concerns me:




Check with your home-contents or bike insurance about coverage too.

It's probably repairable and you should get it repaired.

I have a hard time seeing how a root could have possibly caused this kind of damage.

this bike is from 2010-ish(not completely sure) no coverage. I was hitting a drop, and then the down tube hit a root/stump. It was covered in leaves
